# Create WebBrowser object as specific user

Tags: winforms, internet-explorer, c#-4.0

When we Shift + right click on IE icon we get options to run as administrator or different user.

can we do similar with creating WebBrowser object and rendering and URL?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different options that may be appropriate, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.  You can:

- [Use RunAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680046(v=vs.85).aspx) to register a class to run as a user.
- [Elevate the .EXE](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSUACSelfElevation-644673d3) through the UAC consent dialog.

It's hard to know which to recommend without knowing the underlying need.

Remember, process integrity, AppContainers, and privilege isolation were put into place as security measures to reduce the impact (and frequency) of malicious behavior.  For developers, that means going through a [few more hoops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717802(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the job done.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance